# How to display graphical images in kitty-terminal using Python

Tags: python

I'm simply wondering how to display an image to kitty-terminal using python. Either display it from raw bytes, or from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For raw images, you can do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/kitty", "icat"], input=rawimage)
```

To display image from file, you can do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/kitty", "icat", "/path/to/image.jpg"])
```

And for image urls, you can do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/kitty", "icat", "https://example.org/image.jpg"])
```